# Microsoft Teams - Post Picture to Channel through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I tried to move channel content to another channel and it works perfectly for messages, files (as attachment), emoji,stickers but for pictures is display it as file and I need to press on it to show me the picture as you can see below:

[image]

The behavior I expect is as follows:

[image]